# Replace null values by the mean of each group

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a dataset similar to below with several columns which contain Nan values.

[image: Dataset sample]

I would like to group the dataset by location and fill the Nan in Iso code and continent column with the same unique string for each location and fill the Nan values with the mean of each location as below:

[image: Desired output]

I have found the code below but it only works for a column at a time and  I would like to do it across all columns apart from Iso code and continent columns.

```
dff['total_deaths'].fillna(dff.groupby('location')['total_deaths'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: FYI, sample and output appear to be the same.

Comment: Wrap the thing that works for one column in a for loop or list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the string columns using `groupby().transform('first')` and the numeric columns using `transform('mean')`, then put the pieces back together (with `location` in the middle) using `concat`:

```py
gb = df.groupby('location')
strCols = ['Iso code','continent']
numCols = list(set(df.columns) - (set(strCols) | set(['location'])))
df = pd.concat([gb[strCols].transform('first'), df['location'], df[numCols].fillna(gb[numCols].transform('mean'))], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Iso code continent     location  new_cases  total_deaths
0      AFG      Asia  afghanistan        5.0           NaN
1      AFG      Asia  afghanistan        7.0           2.0
2      AFG       NaN  afghanistan        8.0           2.0
3      NaN    Europe     portugal        3.0           7.0
4       PT    Europe     portugal        3.0           9.0
5      ANG    Africa       angola        NaN           NaN
6      ANG       NaN       angola        5.0           7.0
7      NaN    Africa       angola        NaN           6.0
  Iso code continent     location  new_cases  total_deaths
0      AFG      Asia  afghanistan        5.0           2.0
1      AFG      Asia  afghanistan        7.0           2.0
2      AFG      Asia  afghanistan        8.0           2.0
3       PT    Europe     portugal        3.0           7.0
4       PT    Europe     portugal        3.0           9.0
5      ANG    Africa       angola        5.0           6.5
6      ANG    Africa       angola        5.0           7.0
7      ANG    Africa       angola        5.0           6.0
```

For the string columns, I have used the value returned by `first` in all rows, not just NaN rows, to ensure uniqueness. If you prefer to just fill NaN in the string columns, you can do this:

```py
df = pd.concat([gb[strCols].fillna(gb[strCols].transform('first')), df['location'], df[numCols].fillna(gb[numCols].transform('mean'))], axis=1)
```

**UPDATED:**

You can automatically identify numeric columns (dtype float64, for example) so that the only special column in the code is `location`, with everything else automated:

```py
gb = df.groupby('location')
numCols = df.dtypes[df.dtypes == 'float64'].reset_index()['index'].to_list()
strCols = list(set(df.columns) - (set(numCols) | set(['location'])))
df = pd.concat([gb[strCols].fillna(gb[strCols].transform('first')), df['location'], df[numCols].fillna(gb[numCols].transform('mean'))], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem with that code is that I have 37 columns in total and I would have to call all of them. Is there any other way to make the code more "clean"?

Comment: Not quite: There are just 3 categories of columns: `location` (which you use for the groupby), `strCols` (which you need to either identify manually or based on dtype) and `numCols` (which get automatically identified as any column other than `location` and `strCols`). There are only 2 calls (not 37) to transform: one for `strCols` and one for `numCols`.

Comment: @Julemb95 See updated answer which automates column classification as string or numeric, with only `location` (the column to group by) actually named in the code.